# Swap/update/change characters of string in scala: Handling with mutable/unmutable strings

Tags: string, scala, swap

I am new to scala language and what i needed is that i want to cyclic rotate a string of characters for example a string = "love", when we perform cyclic rotate this result should be like this string "elov". here is my code which i have written

---

### 1st Method code 1

```
import scala.util.control._
import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.schemagen.xmlschema.List

object StringAlgorithm {

    def swap(s : String, idx1 : Int, idx2 : Int){
        val cs = s.toCharArray
        val swp = cs(idx1)
        cs(idx1) = cs(idx2)
        cs(idx2) = swp
        println(cs)
    }

    def main(args: Array[String}){
        var str2 ="ovel"
        var str2len  = str2.length()
        val LastIndex = str2len -1
        println(LastIndex)
        //val cs = Array[Char](4) 
        //println(cs)
        var i : Int = 0

        for(i <- 0 to LastIndex){
            swap(str2, i, LastIndex)    
        }
        println(str2)

    }
}
```

### Above one is not working

### 2nd  Method code 2

```
object test {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var str = "Hello"
    println(str)
    var str1 = str.toList
    println(str1)
    val str1en = (str1.length) - 1
    println(str1en)


    for ( i <- 0 to str1en){
      var temp = str1(i)
      var temp1 = str1(str1en)
      str1.updated(i, temp1)
      str1.updated(str1en, temp)   
    }
     println(str1)

   }

 }
```

Comment: Does the second one work? What's your question?

Comment: you're programming c in scala

Comment: One solution might be simply: `val word = "love"; val cycled = word.last + word.init`

Comment: Update: no,. the second one doesn't work either. @Łukasz, that's only the first one, from the OP's examples looks like all are needed.

Comment: Those `import`s in the first method are a bit... odd. Why do you think you need them?

Comment: Thanks for the Swift response.. Answer to your queries are : neither 1st one or 2nd one work . those imports have been done automatically i have not import any thing explicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fairly straightfoward Scala-ish solution

```
val str = "Hello"  
for {i <- 1 until str.length
     (a,b) = str.splitAt(i)}
     yield b + a     
// Vector(elloH, lloHe, loHel, oHell)
```

A version using iterators (slightly less Scala-ish?)

```
Iterator.iterate(str){s=>s.last + s.init}.take(str.length).toList
```

More directly using a method from the List companion object

```
List.iterate(str, str.length){s=>s.last + s.init}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Can you please tell me what was wrong in my code ? so that i can avoid it latter

Comment: I really don't know where to start - it appears you've not learnt much Scala yet. Method 1/swap converts the string to a char array, but never returns the char array so whatever it does is discarded. The second creates new strings wiith updated values, but then discards the new strings. Strings are immutable in Scala (and Java), what you're trying is simply the wrong approach

Comment: Thanks !! yes you are right i m very new to scala !!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my idea:

```
def cycleOnce(word: String): String = word.last + word.init

def cycled(word: String) = (1 until word.size)
  .foldLeft(List(word))((list, _) => cycleOnce(list.head) :: list).reverse
```

Use:

```
scala> cycled("love")
res4: List[String] = List(love, elov, velo, ovel)
```

Comment: Thanks Man !! it worked .. :) Also Can you please tell me what waswrong in my code ? so that i can avoid it latter

Comment: Paul gave you some hints. I will add to this a little thing: don't use capital letter to name regular variables like you did with `LastIndex`, use it just for some universal constants (check scala style guide for more things like this). The main problem is that you are programming in scala as if it was c. You should probably go through some examples of code to get the hang of how things are done here. Learn collections api. Scala gives a lot of functions to work with collections and you should use them instead of low level for loops and mutable variables.

Comment: by the way to get the output I shown, result needs to be in reverse order, I somehow didn't paste version with reverse in the first place, I added it now.